# Unexpected token = on first function in a class of React JS

Tags: reactjs, macos, sublimetext3, jsx, babeljs

This code works well, is just annoying to see this error all the time.

So this is very much an error with babel-sublime, and also there is an issue open there but no answer just yet. Link to issue: https://github.com/babel/babel-sublime/issues/363.

The problem is, when you create a class in ReactJs, and then create two functions inside this class, the first one will be coloured as an error saying:

> Unexpected token = (null)

The second function has no error, is always the first. Note that this are arrow functions.

This code will do in Sublime Text 3 with babel-sublime package installed:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    class MyComponent extends Component {
        firstFunction = () => {
            return false;
        }
        secondFunction = () => {
            return false;
        }
        thirdFunction = () => {
            return false;
        }
        render() {
            return(
                <div>
                    Component
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
    export default MyComponent;
```

No matter what theme or color scheme are you using, this error will be present. I put a screenshot here so you can see the different color from the first function and the second and so on (no error present in the screenshot because I deactivated it on the linter rules).

[image]

**EDIT:** I am putting my .eslintrc contents for you to see if something is making this error show up.

```
{
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "ecmaFeatures": {
    "modules": true,
    "arrowFunctions": true,
    "classes": true
  },
  "env": {
    "node": true,
    "browser": true,
    "es6": true,
  },
  "rules": {
    "no-console": 0,
    "no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs": 0,
    "react/prop-types": 0,
    "react/no-unescaped-entities": 0,
    "react/no-string-refs": 0,
    "no-useless-escape": 0,
    "no-irregular-whitespace": 0,
    "strict": 0
  },
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
  ],
  "parserOptions": {
      ecmaVersion: 6,
      ecmaFeatures: {
          jsx: true,
      },
      sourceType: "module"
  },
}
```

Comment: I think my actual .eslintrc is not the problem, but just to discard this as a possible problem, I edited the question so you can tell me if something is making this happen.

Answer (score 0):

Have your tried checking here ? https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/479

Have you also tried to enable the babel-eslint in your .eslintrc file ?
Try install it from

```
$ npm install eslint@4.x babel-eslint@8 --save-dev
```

## or

```
$ yarn add eslint@4.x babel-eslint@8 -D
```

then includes this config in your eslint config file (.eslintrc)

```
{
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "rules": {
    "strict": 0
  }
}
```

Wish it could help!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I installed this, but globally, still no changes. For the .eslintrc file, I already had the parser set as babel-eslint, and adding the strict rule as 0 made no difference.